# Restrict users to view a particular page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, spgroup, spuser

i have a sharepoint site http://spp/sitepages/page2.aspx

I have a group called "Group1" with full control. There are two users "User1" and "User2".So both the users will have full control and both of them can make any changes in page2.aspx. Now this is my requirement, i want to allow only "User1" to access, when "User2" access my page i want to show "Access Denied" is it possible without code.

Comment: If this is a "no code" question it belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com .  The obvious solution is to adjust the permissions you have granted to User2

Comment: What's wrong with the SharePoint Stackexchange community, Trikks?

Answer (score 2):

Since we can't vote to close towards sharepoint.se yet, here it goes:

You need to go to the SitePages library in the browser, select the page you want to change permissions and then go to the dropdown menu for the item > Manage Permissions > Edit Permissions (Stop Inheriting), remove all users / groups and only add User1 to the item.

A more detailed guide is available at the [Microsoft Office website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-item-HA101967079.aspx) online

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your page into a document library - do so. This way you can adjust your permissions properly with no code.